Is there a way to place a line in a Power BI Matrix?
I am here to ask for help with an issue I am having.  I developed a matrix that shows data items on the left and dates on the top.  What I have been asked to do is to separate the 48 months out by year with a line going vertical on the matrix.  Does anyone know how I can place a vertical line in a matrix between two specific dates (not all of them) that as the customer scrolls to the right on the matrix, the line keeps moving with the data?  Thank you.

The first and simple idea that comes to mind is to just add an external line, put it in place and when you scroll the matrix you should have the effect you need. otherwise play with the settings of the grid (Format > Visual > Grid > Vertical Gridlines)

I did that, but when I scroll to the right in the matrix the line stays in that spot.  I need it to move along with the data.
